# Open/Update a Java program project that is in deployed package

Tags: java

Is it possible to open and update a java program source code in IDE like Netbeans that is in deploy packaging format? The program contains a couple of JFrame, JPanel, JOptionPane only and I need to refurbish its layout but unfortunately we no longer have the source code thus not sure where to start or is it even possible to do modification at this case.

This is the package with the bat file as the program launcher

[image]

bat file content `@echo off start bin\javaw -classpath lib -DLANG=EN -splash:lib\splash.png App`

The bin file mostly contains dll and exe there is also no src folder anywhere.

Comment: Decompile, modify, recompile, repackage.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen what file should I decompile in this case?

Comment: Impossible for me to even guess. Probably you're looking for a JAR file that you need to extract and then decompile the classes in that JAR file. Looks like it will be in the `lib` folder.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen so the thing that I need to decompile is only JAR file to modify it right and recompile it?

Comment: I don't have a copy of your application, so that's the most I can tell you based on the information provided.